# Is there an easy way to convert string of ints to individual ints

Tags: java, string, int

I am able to do this:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

so that `int foo = 123`

Given that:

```
String numbers = "1 2 3"; //note the separation by a space if that helps

int first=
int second=
int third=
```

Is there an easy way to write the above so that each int first, second and third corresponds to its appropriate position?

Comment: is that the input is seperated by space?

Comment: If they're separated by space, call `split()` and the `parseInt` on the resulting elements.

Comment: yes they are split by a space, i forgot to add that they can be a 2 digit number as well and need to assess each individual number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the input and convert that to string array using `split` method, Iterate over that array of string and convert each string to `char` array. Please see the below code

```
String str = "12 3 1 265";
    String[] strArray = str.split(" ");

    for(String s : strArray){
      char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
      for(char c : charArray){
         // your logic to parse and store
          System.out.println(c);
      }
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @30iT wants to change it to integers.  Also you should put `str.toCharArray()` inside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you kindly would upvote if i could, still a few points shy :D but thanks

Comment: @30iT Accept this as an answer as it is resolved your problem

Answer (score 2):

if it is not separate by space, alternative solution :

```
String numbers = "123";
int foo = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
int[] nums = new int[numbers.length()];
int i=0;
  while (foo > 0) {
   nums[i] = foo % 10;
   number = foo / 10;
   i++
  }
```

if it is separate by space , split using non numeric character and convert into number.

```
    String numbers = "1 2 3";
    String s[] =numbers.split("\\D+");
    int[] nums = new int[s.length];
       for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
                nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop.

```
String numbers = "123456789";
        int[] nums = new int[numbers.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++){
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+numbers.charAt(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Space can be avoided . So let the code be :

1st Way :

```
    String numbers []  = {"1" , "2" , "3"};
    int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
    int thirdNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);
    // strings are now parsed
```

2nd Way :

```
   private String numbers = new String[3] ;
   numbers[0] = "1" ;
   numbers[1] = "2" ;
   numbers[2] = "3" ;
   int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
   int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
   int thirdNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);
   // strings are now parsed
```

3rd Way :
   (Using a for loop) Note : A for loop can initialize multiple variables

```
  int numArray = new int(3);
  String strNum = {"1" , "2" , "3"} ;

 for( int ic ; int i ; ic < 3;  ic ++){
        i += 1 ;
        numArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNum[ic]);
  }
```

I would recommend for loop only if there are more numbers .  For a string of three numbers , induvidual  assignment is preferrable .

Hope I helped you .

Comment: Terrible answer, even your `for loop` syntax is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="12 23 76 87 98";
        while (s.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,s.indexOf(" "))));
            s=s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")+1, s.length());
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,s.length()))); // for last integer


Output:
12
23
76
87
98
```